# Python Excel date/time read in issue

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to read dates/time off an excel sheet using Python, but I only want to read in the time so I can perform computations on it. For example if I have a date in the format: `3/11/2003  4:03:00 AM`
on my excel sheet how can I read in just the `4:03:00` in Python? I ultimately want to be able to subtract hours, mins, or seconds from the read in time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best option would be to convert the date to [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) using [`xldate_as_tuple`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function). Assuming you have an `test.xls` file with `3/11/2003 4:03:00 AM` in the `A1` cell:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename='test.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

date = sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
datetime_value = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date, 0))

print datetime_value  # prints 2003-11-03 04:03:00
print datetime_value.time()  # 04:03:00
print datetime_value - timedelta(hours=1)  # prints 2003-11-03 03:03:00
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok so I have read in the date and time from the excel sheet and stored in a variable called date, but when `print date` in python it outputs `37691.16875`. Im not sure what format this is but after doing some searching this is how dates from excel sheets are read into python. SO I guess my real question is how to convert `37691.16875` in to `3/11/2003  4:03:00 AM`

Comment: Ive tried that as well but I get an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Data Cleaner.py", line 104, in <module>
    Rule_2(sheet)
  File "Data Cleaner.py", line 31, in Rule_2
    date = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(c_val, book.datemode)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xldate.py", line 61, in xldate_as_tuple
    xldays = int(xldate)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` any ideas?

Comment: You were right. my problem was that there were some blank fields in some of the cells and thats why my program was crashing. Thanks for the help!!!