# xldate_as_tuple not working

Tags: python, excel, date, xlrd

Im reading in dates and times from an excel sheet in python. The dates are store as a floating point number, for example the date: `3/11/2003  4:03:00` in excel is read in to python as `37756.2180556`. In python im trying to convert this decimal number back into a regular date using `xlrd.xldate_as_tuple` but im getting an error.

```
def Rule_2(sheet):
x = 2
y = 0
total_rows = sheet.nrows
total_columns = sheet.ncols
while y != total_columns:
    column_name = sheet.cell(0,y).value
    if column_name == "birthday":
        while x != total_rows:
            c_val = sheet.cell(x,y).value
            date = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(c_val, book.datemode)
            print "row:", x + 1, date
            x += 1
    y += 1
```

This code produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Data Cleaner.py", line 104, in <module>
    Rule_2(sheet)
  File "Data Cleaner.py", line 31, in Rule_2
    date = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(c_val, book.datemode)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xldate.py", line 61, in xldate_as_tuple
    xldays = int(xldate)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Any ideas on how to fix this, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not start by debugging this and printing `c_val` before each conversion... `xlrd` has no problems doing the conversion - it's just you're trying to apply it to empty cells... Check the `Cell`'s `.ctype` is `xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE` before hand

Comment: Why didn't i think of that!!!! your 100% correct its working now. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Excel date/time read in issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685191/python-excel-date-time-read-in-issue)